# Passing special char in javascript

Tags: javascript, servlets, alphanumeric, param

How to pass the * sign in javascript method.

Here is the scenerio..

```
String gridName = ServletRequest.getStringParameter(req, "gridName", "");
outHTML.append("createModal('OrderEntryFrame,'.append(gridName))"); //Throws ERROR
```

i have received gridName value *Port at runtime.

So is there any way so i can prevent it and pass it to JS.

Comment: * alwayz at first position.

Comment: Yes Mike it always at fisrt, comming from DB

Comment: Then use substring...

Comment: I required the value as it is on the other function, i.e with * somtims there is 2 astricks ** in data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to pass ASCII * as a character, did you try using the \ operator? i.e. "\*" w/o quotes of course.

Comment: DB stores this value in format like (*Port, %Porttt) we have to just pass from JAVA to JS. then how to put the escapeSequence